# Motodev Library Project

Tags: android, project

Hy

Does someone knows if motodev support the creation of an "library project"?
 Searching the oficial [motodev forum](http://community.developer.motorola.com/t5/MOTODEV-Studio-for-Android/Android-library-projects/m-p/5557/highlight/false#M677) i found a post from 2010 that says that the 1.2.1 version has this option. Did they drop it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a reply at the MOTODEV Forums, but to quote here ...

See http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject  ("Setting up a Library Project" in the Android Dev Guide). Quoting Google, "A library project is a standard Android project, so you can create a new one in the same way as you would a new application project." You then open your project's "Android" properties and select "Is Library".

[image: Library Project in Android settings]

Thanks for using MOTODEV Studio!

-E